# Want to pass String to Query Spring data with @query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, jpql

I just want to pass two string to my query with Spring data, 
my query looks like :

```
@Query("select ts.talent from T_LinkTalentSkill ts , where ts.skill || '_'||ts.lnLevel in (a,b) group by 1 having count(*)=2 ")
public List<T_Talent> searchBySkillTalent(@Param("a") String a,@Param("b") String b);
```

i tried to pass a and b but i got : Validation failed for query

Comment: you have a comma before where (,)

Comment: thank you i forget about it :p

Comment: Since when has "||" been a valid operator in JPQL?! JPQL has CONCAT

Comment: when i tested without params like this "in ('1_1','9_1')" it works fine

Comment: Not only is || invalid, also COUNT(*) is invalid. Why not read the JPA spec if not believing me? JPQL != SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `@Query` annotation with native queries you need to use `nativeQuery` flag with `true` value, please check below code:

```
@Query(value = "select ts.talent from T_LinkTalentSkill ts  where ts.lnLevel in (?1,?2) group by 1 having count(*)=2", nativeQuery = true)
List<T_Talent> searchBySkillTalent(String a,String b);
```